# join two table with a primary and foreign keys with a different format

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Two tables:

```
employee
id name
1  steve
2  rob
3  bell

position     
position_id employee_id position
1           e1         manager
2           e2         seller
3           e3         director
```

the problem is that the foreign key has a different format than the primary key.
how can I get the result using sql query?

```
name   position
steve  manager
rob    seller
bell   director
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saying your `employee_id` in your position table always has an "e" prefixed to it?  If so, then this should work using `CONCAT`:

```
select e.name, p.position
from employee e join position p
on p.employee_id = concat('e',e.id)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/630e3/2)

Comment: your solution work like a charm, and the effort you put to create the SQL Fiddle Demo was highly appreciated!! thank you very much Sgeddes!!!!!

Comment: @mongotop -- np in the least, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

**[CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)**
 function will help you implicitly convert your numeric id and add 'e' in front to match your employee_id in position table. Then you can do a hash join to get result from two tables.
 
**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74a9b/4)**

```
select E.name, 
       P.position
from Employee E 
inner join Positions P
    on P.employee_id = concat('e',E.id)
```